# Decline Outlook meeting based on recipient being a distribution list?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, office-automation, distribution-list

I get emails from my old team/role about tech bridges during outages that I no longer attend. I would like to auto-decline them IF they are sent to a specific distribution list (that I'm still part of).

I don't know VBA at all but would this work (I modified another script I found and replaced SenderEmailAddress with Recipients). Don't want to run this until someone who actually knows that they are looking at confirms or denies that this will work (on the off chance it does something wild with me emails).

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
Dim xEntryIDs
Dim xItem
Dim i As Integer
Dim xMeeting As MeetingItem, xMeetingDeclined As MeetingItem
Dim xAppointmentItem As AppointmentItem
On Error Resume Next
xEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(xEntryIDs)
    Set xItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(xEntryIDs(i))
    If xItem.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
        Set xMeeting = xItem
        xMeeting.ReminderSet = False
        If VBA.LCase(xMeeting.Recipients) = VBA.LCase("support.bridge@company.com") Then 
            Set xAppointmentItem = xMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
            xAppointmentItem.ReminderSet = False
            Set xMeetingDeclined = xAppointmentItem.Respond(olMeetingDeclined)
            xMeetingDeclined.Body = "Declined"
            xMeetingDeclined.Send
            xMeeting.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare the Recipients collection with a string in the following way:

```
If VBA.LCase(xMeeting.Recipients) = VBA.LCase("support.bridge@company.com") Then
```

The [MeetingItem.Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem.recipients) property returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. Use `Recipients(index)`, where `index` is the name or index number, to return a single `Recipient` object. The name can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient.

The [Recipient.DisplayType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.displaytype) property returns a constant belonging to the [OlDisplayType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldisplaytype) enumeration that describes the nature of the `Recipient`. It seems you are interested in the `olDistList` or `olPrivateDistList` values.

Also I've noticed the following line of code:

```
xEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
```

The `NewMailEx` behavior has been changed more than 10 years ago and now it is fired for each Outlook item separately. So, there is no need to split the string in the event handler, the parameter contains only a single entry ID value.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for the response. I'm not sure I understood all of that, but I made the changes recommended and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Thoughts on where I went wrong?

Mainly I removed the Split like you mentioned and my main IF statement is:

If VBA.LCase(xMeeting.Recipients("bridge@company.com")) Or VBA.LCase(xMeeting.Recipients("bridge2@company.com")) Then

Comment: Use the index (number) to get recipients. I'd suggest declaring each recipient separately or try to access them in the loop, so that you could debug the code.

Comment: Okay, I'm at a loss and lack the understanding/VBA knowledge to proceed further/digest what you've stated. I think I'll have to abandon this and hope that Microsoft eventually adds a rule for this.

Comment: Try to start from the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) page.